Combinatorial interpretation wanted: Two-player coin flip game; first to $n$ heads wins
Two players take turns flipping a fair coin; the first to get $n$ heads wins. The probability that the first player wins this game is given by the infinite sum
$$\sum_{i\ge n}\sum_{0\le j<n}{1\over2^{2i-1}}{i-1\choose n-1}{i-1\choose j},$$
since we can represent any game where the first player wins as a sequence of length $2i-1$ of flips ‘H’ or ‘T’ that ends with ‘H’; we then choose the $n-1$ rounds in which the first player flipped heads, and the $0\le j<n$ rounds in which the second player flipped heads.
From a previous question (Why is $\sum_{i\ge n}{3^{2n-1}\over2^{2i-1}}{i-1\choose n-1}{i-1\choose j}$ an integer?), I learned that the infinite sum above can, with some effort, be rewritten as a finite sum
$${2\over3^{2n-1}}\sum_{0\le i\le j<n}3^{n-1-j+i}{n-1+j-i\choose j}{j\choose i}.\tag{$*$}$$
Moreover, each term in this sum (ignoring the $2/3^{2n-1}$ factor) is a product of three integers, and the numbers all seem quite nice. As such, my question is:

Is there a bijective/combinatorial argument for why the probability of the first player winning is given by ($*$)?

Presumably this is intimately connected with the fact that this probability can be written as $A(n,n)$, where $$A(m,n)=\begin{cases}
1&\hbox{if $m=0$;}\\
0&\hbox{if $m\ge1$ and $n=0$;}\\
{1\over3}\bigl(A(m-1,n)+A(m,n-1)+A(m-1,n-1)\bigr)&\hbox{if $m,n\ge1$};
\end{cases}$$
the idea being that $A(m,n)$ gives the probability that the first player wins, given that it’s the first player’s turn and that he is $m$ heads away from winning, whereas the second player is $n$ heads away from winning. But I haven't been able to tease out the details.

Let's say that a round consists of a turn by the first player and a turn by the second player. We can skip all rounds in which both players flip tails, and so we can think of each round as being uniformly chosen from the three results HH, HT, and TH.
With this setup, there are $3^{2n-1}$ sequences of $2n-1$ rounds, and after $2n-1$ rounds, one player is guaranteed to win; so let's figure out the probability that it's the first player.
Suppose that the first player wins on round $a+b+c+1$, where in the first $a+b+c$ rounds, there are $a$ results of HT, $b$ results of HH, and $c$ results of TH. Then there are $\binom{a+b+c}{b+c} \binom{b+c}{b}$ ways to choose the results of the first $a+b+c$ rounds, $2$ ways to choose the result of the winning round (it must be HH or HT), and $3^{2n-a-b-c-2}$ ways to choose results of the rounds after the first player's victory. The probability that the first player wins is
$$
    \frac{2}{3^{2n-1}} \sum_{(a,b,c)} 3^{2n-a-b-c-2} \binom{a+b+c}{b+c} \binom{b+c}{b} 
$$
where the sum is over all valid triples $(a,b,c)$.
Not all triples $(a,b,c)$ are possible, of course. We must have $a+b = n-1$, because the first player reaches $n$ points on round $a+b+c+1$, and we must have $b+c \le n-1$ or $c \le a$, because the second player shouldn't win before the first player does. Within these constraints, anything goes. To match the sum in the question, we carefully choose the parameterization $$(a,b,c) = (n-i-1, i, j-i)$$ where the constraints on $a$, $b$, and $c$ turn into the constraints $0 \le i \le j < n$. With this substitution, the probability we want becomes exactly the probability we wanted:
$$
\frac{2}{3^{2n-1}} \sum_{0 \le i \le j < n} 3^{n-1-j+i} \binom{n-1+j-i}{j} \binom{j}{i}.
$$
